# Does winding a choke inductor produce a transformer?

Tags: transformer, inductor

I obtained schematics and build instructions for a device which generates low current, high voltage (50-100V) signals. The high voltages are generated from a normal 5V USB supply.

The instructions specify to get a 390µH fixed inductor (the [Bourns 5800-391-RC](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/5800-391-RC/M8297-ND/774837) to be precise), and wind magwire around it 16 times. The ends of the inductor are connected to the high-voltage section, and the ends of the magwire are connected to the input signal (0-5V).

This implies that the inductor is acting as a transformer (assuming the instructions are correct). That makes sense, since in some sense there's a winding on the inside (the inductor's winding) and a winding on the outside of a magnetic core. But I've never seen a transformer constructed this way.

If this is in fact a legitimate way to construct a transformer, then (a) how can I compute the transformer's voltage ratio (given that I don't know how many turns are inside the inductor), and (b) how does this actually work electronically?

EDIT: Here's the relevant part of the schematic (from EAGLE).

> [image: Schematic]

The part in question looks like a transformer, and is labeled TRANSFORMER in the document. The capacitors are on the "high-voltage" side of the circuit, and the "V+" and transistor on the left are on the "low-voltage" side of the circuit.

Comment: A schematic would help with the question part b.

Comment: @Daniel: Added the relevant part of the schematic.

Comment: That circuit diagram has to be wrong - there is no diode in the secondary to rectify the output. Where did you get this circuit from?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to estimate the turns ratio by putting a sine wave across the primary of the transformer, then measuring the unloaded AC voltage on the secondary. The ratio of voltage should be proportional to the turns ratio.

You could probably get a better answer by sweeping the frequency and taking the max value.

The circuit works by switching the MOSFET (which you've half-included) on and off to generate an AC voltage. This is a very basic form of flyback converter (although it's missing a diode, so the output will be AC).

You can read about flyback converters here: http://www.dos4ever.com/flyback/flyback.html

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF7hWF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Update:
I got curious, then confused, then determined.. I think your circuit may have a problem... Check out this simulation. I think it does what you're wanting. Leaving out the diode gave me some pretty gnarly looking AC output voltage. Also note the addition of C2 to 'catch' the current from the collapsing magnetic field in the transformer primary. In this simulation, Vsw peaks near 60V, which would not be terribly good unless you're using a suitably rated MOSFET.